# How should I copy a smaller 2d array to a big 2d array using matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

If I have an 100x20 array and I want to copy multiple 30x3 array into the big array, what's the best way to do it in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
big = zeros(100, 20);
a = rand(30, 3);
b = rand(30, 3);
big(1:30, 1:3) = a;
big(1:30, 4:6) = b;
```